# Magento 1.8.1 Not sending Order/Invoice emails

Tags: magento, email

I'm having an issue where my emails don't send to the client, or a copy to myself.

My website is hosted with one company, but my emails are on godaddy, and I had to set the MX records on my hosting differently.  Do I need to change any settings on the website to reflect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using multiple languages and have have copied the translated files in locale from->to ?

1. Go in "System > Transactional Emails" and create there the translated templates.
2. Go in "System > Configuration > Sales Email" and select for each (Order,   invoice...) the before created Template from Transactional Email.